# get roles assigned to user in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, roles

I have a postgreSQl database. I have created few users of the database and assigned certain roles to each user. In my python program I need to get the users of the database along with their corresponding roles. How to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform queries against the [system catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html). Try looking in the [`pg_user`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-user.html) and [`pg_roles`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-roles.html) tables. Their schemas are:

```
test=# \d pg_user
     View "pg_catalog.pg_user"
    Column    |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------------+---------+-----------
 usename      | name    | 
 usesysid     | oid     | 
 usecreatedb  | boolean | 
 usesuper     | boolean | 
 userepl      | boolean | 
 usebypassrls | boolean | 
 passwd       | text    | 
 valuntil     | abstime | 
 useconfig    | text[]  | 

test=# \d pg_roles
              View "pg_catalog.pg_roles"
     Column     |           Type           | Modifiers 
----------------+--------------------------+-----------
 rolname        | name                     | 
 rolsuper       | boolean                  | 
 rolinherit     | boolean                  | 
 rolcreaterole  | boolean                  | 
 rolcreatedb    | boolean                  | 
 rolcanlogin    | boolean                  | 
 rolreplication | boolean                  | 
 rolconnlimit   | integer                  | 
 rolpassword    | text                     | 
 rolvaliduntil  | timestamp with time zone | 
 rolbypassrls   | boolean                  | 
 rolconfig      | text[]                   | 
 oid            | oid                      |
```

Assuming that you are using `psycopg2` to connect to the database with Python you can execute queries against the system catalog tables:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="test", user='postgres')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from pg_catalog.pg_user')
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)

cur.execute('select * from pg_catalog.pg_roles')
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Comment: This lists all the users & roles in the DBMS. But, not users with their corresponding roles.

Comment: But this method gives me only the list of users and roles. I need the users with their corresponding roles. How can I achieve it?

Comment: There are some logic errors in this program, here is the correct program...         `import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user='postgres')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from pg_catalog.pg_user')
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)

cur.execute('select * from pg_catalog.pg_roles')
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)`         correct the indentation. but this program only gives  the list of users and roles. and not a solution.

Comment: @Aravind: perform a join on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, derived by combining 2 different queries of the previous program into a single query based on a SQL WHERE condition (Assuming that you are **using psycopg2 to connect to the database with Python**)

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user='postgres')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT usename,rolname FROM pg_user,pg_roles WHERE oid=usesysid;')
#print ('users&roles')
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row[0]+','+row[1])
```

Comment: Just to see the result, i have created 4 users and 2 roles in a database and granted assigned roles to 3 users.But,  I can see the users also in pg_roles table. So I am getting the result as, 
    user1,user1.  Not as user1, role1

Comment: try `print(row)` instead of `print(row[0]+','+row[1])`. Verify your results by executing the query `SELECT usename,rolname FROM pg_user,pg_roles WHERE oid=usesysid;` on a pgadmin console.

Comment: '('postgres', 'postgres')
('user1', 'user1')
('user2', 'user2')
('user3', 'user3')
('user4', 'user4')'.. This is the result I am getting